# Creating lists do not include duplicates in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

```
**FACTS**
player(milan,[seedorf,zambrotta,gattuso]).
player(inter,[seedorf,ronaldo,zambrotta]).
player(realmadrid,[seedorf,zidane,ronaldo]).
```

i wanna create a predicate such that :

```
find (TEAM, PLAYERS)
```

and if my goal is **find(X,Y)** it will returns List of teams,X, and List of players,Y, without any duplicates... Like below:

```
X=[milan], Y=[seedorf,zambrotta,gattuso];
X=[inter], Y=[seedorf,ronaldo,zambrotta];
X=[realmadrid], Y=[seedorf,zidane,ronaldo]; 
X=[milan,inter] Y=[seedorf,zambrotta];
X=[milan,realmadri] Y=[seedorf]; 
...
X=[milan,inter,realmadrid] Y=[seedorf];
...
```

i try to do this with but it gives "ERROR: Out of local stack",
If i do not use remove_dups predicate, 
The list of teams,"X", would have duplicates and program could not stop...
keep going like X=[milan,milan,milan,milan,inter] .... How can i correct this code. ?:

```
find([X], Y) :- player(X1, Y),remove_dups(X1,X).
find([X|Xs], Y) :- player(X1, Y0),find(Xs, Y3), intersection(Y0, Y3, Y),remove_dups(X1,X).

remove_dups([],[]).
remove_dups([First|Rest],NewRest):-member(First, Rest),remove_dups(Rest, NewRest).
remove_dups([First|Rest],[First|NewRest]):-not(member(First, Rest)),remove_dups(Rest, NewRest).
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Just to clarify, predicate **find/2** should return all (nonempty?) subsets of teams (as a list in first argument) and the corresponding list of players common to all those teams.  Based on the examples, it appears you would not return "successfully" if the list of players were empty (but you might address that requirement).

Comment: i didn't understand ? i write a code that look lists are not empty. but it still return duplicates...

Comment: Hi, Michael... I'm clear that you *don't* want duplicates in the results.  What my comment was aimed at clarifying is what you do want.  It may be clear to you what the predicate is intended to do, but your description ("it will returns List of teams,X, and List of players,Y, without any duplicates") is not a specification of what it should do.  The reader is left to fill in blanks based on your examples, and there is room for misinterpretation of the spec.  Hence my question:  Should there be a result (not duplicated of course) where a subset of teams produces the empty list of players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do pattern matching on a list of `Xs`, it always puts in the same value of `milan` so there are a lot of duplication. You can avoid it by first ensuring no duplication in the list of `Xs` and finding corresponding players:

```
subset([], []).
subset(Xs, [_|Ys]) :- subset(Xs, Ys).
subset([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- subset(Xs, Ys).

allteams(Ts) :- findall(T, player(T, _), Ts).
teams(T) :- allteams(Ts), subset(T, Ts).

find1([T], L) :- player(T, L).
find1([T|Ts], L) :- player(T, L0), find1(Ts, L1), intersection(L0, L1, L).

find(X, Y) :- teams(X), find1(X, Y).
```

Here I find a set of all teams first and try to find subsets satisfying the condition.